# Qual alternativa ao método obsoleto (conforme MDN) document.execCommand?

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer um simples editor de texto com javascript e preciso de uma maneira de formatar um texto dentro de uma `div` que está servindo como um `textArea`.

Procurei algumas maneiras na internet e todas usam o método `document.execCommand`, porém segundo o [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) esse método está obsoleto:

[image: Mensagem da MDN sobre execCommand estar obsoleto]

Existe algum método alternativo que eu possa fazer o mesmo processo de formatar o texto dentro da div?

Comment: O mais estranho é que somente nesta página do MDN fala isso, as demais que falam do mesmo comando como https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard, apesar da principal ter sido editada em Janeiro de 2020, mas não consigo ter certeza se isto foi confusão de quem editou (o MDN é comunitário), no site w3.org (https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/) e outros não fala nada sobre o desuso e remoção deste método, esta me parecendo confusão, mas não posso afirmar, afinal, humanos editam, algo sempre fica para trás.

Comment: **Nota:** usei o comando e nenhum navegador emitiu Warning/Avisos quando usei o comando, nem mesmo o Firefox. Geralmente quando uma função, método, maneira de usar ou sintaxe ou API estão em desuso os navegadores informam, claro que isto se for algo que já tem um tempo e já foi ajustado no navegador para emitir. Lembrando que a MDN é também responsavel pelo Firefox

Comment: Pois então, também achei muito estranho mas fiquei meio que com um pé atrás na hora de usar e algum dia parar de funcionar...

Comment: E é difícil porque não encontro nada que consiga preencher as funcionalidades do método

Comment: Por isso mesmo, estou achando que algum redator fez confusão na MDN, as edições sendo comunitárias ainda piora, claro que na maioria ajuda, mas volta e meia rola uma barbeiragem. Tem como fazer sem, mas o unico meio que vejo é manipular o DOM com activeElement+selectRange e customizar manualmente (o que funcionaria, mas é bem trabalhoso).